# using Ebean, fill property value of entity list stored another related entity property

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.5

I'll try to describe my question with codes directly and will say what I need after, note that I minimized my code to ficus on the issue that I have:

I get list of feed from Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Feed {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_trigger_id")
    private EventTypeTrigger eventTrigger;
}
```

Here I'm trying to get this Entity filled with correct `count` value.

```
@Entity
public class EventTrigger {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Transient
    private int count;
}
```

The feed entity that store the count data.

```
@Entity
public class EventTriggerFeed {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;


    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int count;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Event event;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_trigger_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private EventTrigger eventTrigger;
}
```

And from service that I try to call:

```
public List<Feed> findUserFeeds(int userId) {
        return Ebean.find(Feed.class).findList();
    }
```

I can get count for each Trigger like this :

```
public int getCountFromEventTriggerFeed(int triggerId, int eventId) {
        return Ebean.find(EventTriggerFeed.class)
                .where().eq("eventTrigger.id",triggerId).eq("event.id",eventId)
                .findUnique().getCount();
    }
```

I simply want to get list of `Feed`, that have `Event` info and `EventTrigger` info, and with `count` property filled with count value from `EventTriggerFeed`

I just kinda stuck with perfect way without so much iteration, i'm thinking about get the count value for each `EventTrigger` inside `Feed` row, but it could lead me to a lot of calls:

```
for (Feed feed : findUserFeeds(userId)) {
    int eventId = feed.getEvent().getId();
    int triggerId = feed.getEventTrigger().getId();
    feed.getEventTrigger().setCount(getCountFromEventTriggerFeed(triggerId, eventId))
}
```

But can you imagine if I have like 50 feeds?

Is there any idea about how to optimize this headache?

Comment: It looks like you can do this with a single bulk update statement. You should look at trying to do that (a single SQL update statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with creating view in `.sql` file something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `event_feed_summary_view` AS
  SELECT
    max(feed.trigger_count) * up.amount AS total_amount,
    feed.trigger_count,
    uf.feed_id,
    feed.event_id,
    feed.event_trigger_id,
    up.amount
  FROM event_trigger_feeds feed
    INNER JOIN event_type_triggers trig ON feed.event_trigger_id AND trig.id
    INNER JOIN user_feed uf ON uf.event_id = feed.event_id AND uf.event_trigger_id = feed.event_trigger_id
  GROUP BY uf.feed_id, feed.event_id, feed.event_trigger_id;
```

I placed this code inside `conf/db_views/create_views.sql`

And I called this file on started up inside my Module `OnStartup` :

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartup {

    @Inject
    public OnStartup(final Configuration configuration, final Environment environment, Database db) {


        // Create views
            Logger.info("Creating / Replacing the Tables views in database");
            InputStream is = environment.classLoader().getResourceAsStream("db_views/create_views.sql");
            String sql;
            try {
                sql = IOUtils.toString(is);
                if (sql != null) {
                    Connection conn = db.getConnection();
                    try {
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                        try {
                            stmt.execute(sql);
                            Logger.info("Views Created");
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                stmt.close();
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        Logger.error("Could create Statement ");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            conn.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error("Could not find create view script");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

with Ebean I get the result with `SqlQuery` :

```
public long getTotal(int feedId) {
    String sql = "select sum(total_amount) as total from event_feed_summary_view where feed_id = :feed_id;";
    SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("feed_id", feedId);
    SqlRow r = sqlQuery.findUnique();
    if (r != null && r.getLong("total") != null) {
        return r.getLong("total");
    }
    return 0;
}
```